# Cooling requirements of solid state relay

Tags: heat, solid-state-relay

In the manual of my solid state relay it is mentioned that they recommend using a heat sink with the SSR and if the current exceeds a certain limit (almost 2 magnitudes above what I need) they additionally recommend using active cooling with a fan. Since if possible I would really like to avoid installing a heatsink, I've been doing some reading about SSRs and recommendations about cooling. I've found articles recommending heat sinks when current exceeds 4A, others 10A. I assume this is also related to what current the SSR is rated for. I have an SSR rated for 30A and I am going to have 230V AC with roughly 250mA of current run through it for several hours a day. It will be mounted in a plastic box where it should ideally not exceed 85°C. The box is not sealed and has a rather powerful fan installed but it is not directed at the SSR (yet).

I am now wondering if I even realistically have to worry about cooling, can this small amount of current even generate enough heat to be a problem?

Comment: Probably not, but how would we know without a link to the datasheet for your relay?

Comment: [http://www.crydom.com/en/tech/white-papers/hs_wp_hs.pdf](http://www.crydom.com/en/tech/white-papers/hs_wp_hs.pdf). Of course the values for Thermal Resistance and "On" Voltage Drop should come from the datasheet of your relay. Cooling will probably not be an issue.

Comment: Thats a very helpful link, the voltage drop is specified as <= 1.5V, so I am going with 1.5V but I am still piecing together the thermal resistance, there are some... language barriers

Comment: Power dissipation of a triac or SCR type SSR is typically around 1W per ampere of load current. If your SSR is rated at 30A it's probably in a package that will easily dissipate 0.25W without a heatsink.

Comment: Should be fine, though the "should ideally not exceed 85C" is a bit worrisome.  AC relays are generally specified with an on-state voltage drop instead of an on-state resistance because they will have an SCR instead of a MOSFET.  As others have said, you'll need to take a look at your datasheet but using a typical value of 1.3V with your current draw of 250mA gives 325mW of heat which is trivial for a hockey puck SSR package even without a heatsink.  I'd be more worried about ambient air rising above the SSR's max operating temp which is generally around 70-80C.

Comment: The plastic (ABS) the box is made of will slowly start to lose its rigidity when it’s own temperature goes above 80 degrees, that is why. So I am anyway going to include some buffer of air between the bottom of the SSR and the box and the air moving inside should distribute and move air out of the box pretty quickly, but I will also execute an observed long term test.

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood your comment and I was not clear in my question, I want to ssr not to get hotter than 80 degrees, ambient temperature will be around room temperature.